# How can i get destination marker count by using "point_count" in mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, markerclusterer, mapbox-marker, mapbox-ios

[image]I am working with map-box in ios swift, my code is working good enough until I zoom to the destination marker but when I reach to destination marker, I unable to get any count on destination marker. Below is my code

```
let icon = UIImage(named: "ic_pin")!
        let ic_pin_count_bord = UIImage(named: "ic_pin_count_bord")!
        var coordinates = [[String:AnyObject]]()
        for i in mainModelView.mapData.mapPinsData{
            var pinSet = [String: AnyObject]()
            pinSet["id"] = i.ID as AnyObject
            pinSet["coordinate"] = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: i.cordinates?.coordinates?.last ?? Double(), longitude: i.cordinates?.coordinates?.first ?? Double()) as AnyObject
            coordinates.append(pinSet)
        }
        let features = coordinates.map { coordinate -> MGLPointFeature in
            let pointFeature = MGLPointFeature()
            pointFeature.coordinate = coordinate["coordinate"] as! CLLocationCoordinate2D
            pointFeature.attributes = [
                "id": coordinate["id"] as! String
            ]
            return pointFeature
        }
        // Create an MGLShapeCollectionFeature from the features
     
        // Create an MGLShapeSource using the shapeCollection
        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts", features: features, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: mainModelView.icon.size.width])
        mapView.style?.addSource(source)
      
               // Show unclustered features as icons. The `cluster` attribute is built into clustering-enabled source features.
               // This example requires two style layers to work properly: one for clustered points and one for unclustered points
               let markerLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "ports", source: source)
               markerLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin")
               markerLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster != YES")
                markerLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
               style.addLayer(markerLayer)
               style.setImage(icon, forName: "ic_pin")

               // Create style layer to cluster features as images with labels
               let clusterLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPortsNumbers", source: source)
               clusterLayer.textColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
               clusterLayer.textFontSize = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
               clusterLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
               // Style image clusters
               style.setImage(icon, forName: "ic_pin")

               let stops = [
                   10: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin"),
                   25: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin"),
                   75: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin"),
                   150: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin")
               ]

               // Use expressions to set each cluster's image based on defined stops and display the point count over the corresponding image
               let defaultShape = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin")
        clusterLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(format: "mgl_step:from:stops:(point_count, %@, %@)", defaultShape, stops)
       
        let backgroundLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPortsNumbersBackground", source: source)
        backgroundLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "ic_pin_count_bord") // Use the same image for the background
        style.setImage(ic_pin_count_bord, forName: "ic_pin_count_bord")
        // Configure background layer
        
        let expression = NSExpression(format: "CAST(point_count, 'NSString')")
        backgroundLayer.text = expression
        backgroundLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
        backgroundLayer.textAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
        backgroundLayer.textFontSize = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
        backgroundLayer.textAnchor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "center")
        backgroundLayer.textColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.black)
        backgroundLayer.iconAnchor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "bottom")
        backgroundLayer.iconOffset = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSValue(cgVector: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -10)))
        backgroundLayer.textOffset = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSValue(cgVector: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -4)))
        style.addLayer(backgroundLayer)
        style.addLayer(clusterLayer)
```

I want set the text like if count is more than 1 then I want to manupulate the NSExpression by "Count Images" other wise "1 Image".